# Connect Hyperledger Composer to an existing Fabric installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to deploy a BNA to Hyperledger Fabric created from an AWS template. This is the error I get:

`Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any                                             peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF`

Here is my connection.json:

`{
    "name": "hlfv1",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": ["orderer.example.com"],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com"],
            "certificateAuthorities": ["ca.org1.example.com"]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
}`

And here's `docker ps` (one thing that puzzles me is why there's no CA image):

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
9000084cc703        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-tools:latest         "/bin/bash"              19 hours ago        Up 19 hours                                                          cli
d7d745f1bd6b        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-explorer:latest      "/bin/sh -c /opt/blo…"   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                           fabric-explorer
d97589d31781        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-peer:latest          "peer node start"        19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
b5ac9e98b202        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-orderer:latest       "orderer"                19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
a97f006dfb0f        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-peer:latest          "peer node start"        19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp   peer0.org3.example.com
16a45d40ef99        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-peer:latest          "peer node start"        19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
4c20e7d651ff        763976151875.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-explorer-db:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                           fabric-explorer-db`

I thought I was good connecting to `peer0.org1.example.com` on ports 7051 and 7053.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @bjrnt was a long time ago, I don't remember. I think I just restarted the Fabric.